# How to remove N type of values before the first char in a string

Tags: php, jquery, string

I have many string that can start as :

```
01. - ??:??:?? - My 'string'
01 00:00 - My string - Power of the string
1. - My string - I'm 0 but I need to stay here
??:?? - My string ?? Yes
01 My string. And so on...
```

and so on. So my idea would be to remove all these characters before the first real "char" in the alphabetik (I mean from a-A to z-Z). What's the best way to do this? Regular expression?

I mean, after the first alphabetik char, no special chars must be removed.

I'd like to do this on PHP and jQuery! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "01. - ??:??:?? - My 'string'";

echo preg_replace("/^.*?([a-zA-Z])/", '\1', $string);
```

http://codepad.org/hL2sFeJ8

In JS

```
var string = "01. - ??:??:?? - My 'string'";

string = string.replace(/^.*?([a-zA-Z])/, '$1');
```

Comment: In fact, `00 aaa bbb` won't work ! it store only `aaa` and it ignore `bbb`... ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this regexp

```
$text=preg_replace('^[^a-zA-Z]+','',$text);
```